# How can i add upload size limit when upload image in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

i want to change user profile photo; However i don't know how can i add upload size limit

views.py

```
def profile_photo_upload(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=UploadForm(request.POST, files=request.FILES,instance=request.user.profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            userprofile=form.save(commit=False)
            userprofile.user=request.user
            userprofile.save()
            messages.success(request,"Success")
    else:
        form=UploadForm()
    return render(request,'imageupdate.html',{'form':form})
```

Also, is my code properly? for safety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def file_size(value): # add this to some file where you can import it from
    limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024
    if value.size > limit:
        raise ValidationError('File too large. Size should not exceed 2 MB.')
```

and in your forms.py add this.

```
image = forms.FileField(validators=[file_size])
```

Comment: this is an interesting answer, but I don't understand "add this to some file where you can import it from." Does `from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError` and `def file_size(value): limit = 2 ...` go at the top of the forms.py file? Or does your code go into a different file and is imported to forms.py?